# Font Awesome icons don't show up correctly during development, installed with bower

Tags: sass, font-awesome

I scaffold my app with yo

```
yo gulp-webapp //I create a basic boilerplate with bootstrap sass
```

Then I install FontAwesome

```
bower install font-awesome --save
```

This is what I have on top of my main.scss

```
$icon-font-path: "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

// bower:scss
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
@import "../../bower_components/fontawesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
// endbower
```

Then I add this to my html page

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
```

And if I launch "gulp serve" It only show a white square, instead if I build with "gulp" the result html works correctly.

The result main.css contain all fa class so I think the problem is with this var

```
$fa-font-path:        "../fonts" !default;
```

This var is here: bower_components/font-awesome/scss/-variables.scss

Comment: Did you check to make sure the font exists at the designated location?

Comment: When gulp create the dist folder fonts are in the correct place but during the normal development "../fonts" can't be the correct path

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to set the

```
$fa-font-path: "fonts" !default;
```

in the **main.scss** file before the @import declarations.

That did the trick for me.
Also, from the font awesome page (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) it states:

> PRO: Custom LESS or SASS
>
> Use this method to customize Font Awesome 4.2.0 using LESS or SASS.
>
> Copy the font-awesome/ directory into your project.
>
> Open your project's font-awesome/less/variables.less or font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss and edit the @fa-font-path or $fa-font-path variable to point to your font directory.
>
> `@fa-font-path:   "../font";`
>
> **The font path is relative from your compiled CSS directory.**
>       Re-compile your LESS or SASS if using a static compiler. Otherwise, you should be good to go.
>       Check out the examples to start using Font Awesome!

Comment: For others running into this issue. In simple words the `$fa-font-path: "fonts" !default;` needs to be relative to the main CSS file. Make sure your file path is correct. If you call `$fa-font-path: "fonts" !default;` - put your fonts inside a `fonts` folder .

Comment: This also works when you want to use the Font Awesome CDN

`$fa-font-path: "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/fonts" !default;`

Comment: In `Angular 6`, I use `SCSS` and the `path` is relative to the main file `src/style.scss`.
Therefore the right variable in my case is: `$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";` before the `@import` of `font-awesome`

Answer (score 2):

I use the gulp build process from [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) which uses wiredep to inject the bower dependencies.

But for some reasons the fontawesome does not work out of the box.
Actually I had following problems:

- The font-awesome.css was not injected in the index.html
- When building the dist version the font files were not present in the fonts directory

Finally I found this very helpful message by [silvenon](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp/issues/71)

Append overrides to your bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "webapp",
    "dependencies": {
        "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
        "jquery": "~1.11.0",
        "fontawesome": "~4.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "overrides": {
        "fontawesome": {
            "main": [
                "css/font-awesome.css",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf",
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg"
             ]
         }
     }
}
```

After that the wiredep task will inject the css in the index.html and also copy the font files to the fonts folder.

Comment: this worked for me bad i had to add a hypehn so that it overrides --> "font-awesome"

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the path to the webfonts folder changes from installation to installation. Go into node_modules/@fortawesome and check relative path. I am wondering if this issue happens with PRO version and how to handle this when the application is deployed into production using Jenkins.